# Showing Javascript Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saw a javascript panel in a large javascript application and am trying to just implement the panel code..
To do so I copied and pasted the pieces of code I thought would be useful in geting the panel to work but unfortunately its not working..

The HTML code..

```
<body>
    <div id="rtfm" style="display:none;"></div> <!--help panel-->
<div id="dashboard">
    <a href="#" class="help">syntax help</a><!-- Clicking this shows the panel-->
    </div> 
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
             (function () {
                 Test = function (elt) {
                     var dom = $(elt)
                     var that = {
                         helpPanel: HelpPanel($('#rtfm')),
                         init: function () {
                             $('.help').click(that.showHelp)
                             $(that.helpPanel).bind('closed', that.hideHelp)
                             return that
                         },
                         showHelp: function (e) {
                             that.helpPanel.reveal()
                             dom.find('.help').fadeOut()
                             // trace('help')
                             return false
                         },

                         hideHelp: function (e) {
                             trace('closed')
                             dom.find('.help').fadeIn()
                         }
                     }
                     return that.init()
                 }
             })()
        </script>
        <script src="src/help.js"></script>   
    </body>
```

I'm not very knowledgeable of javascript and would appreciate if someone could help me out..

Thanks..

Comment: How is it not working? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: No error messages on console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ..found the problem..
The following needed to be added to the code after Test to call it..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var mcp = Test()    
            })
```